# Why are some user fields missing from Instagram /user/media/recent API calls?

Tags: api, instagram

I'm receiving inconsistent results when hitting Instagram's `/users/{user-id}` / `/users/search` API endpoints, compared to the `users/{user-id}/media/recent` endpoint.

When I hit the `/users/{user-id}` / `/users/search` endpoints, you can see from the example below I receive fields such as `website` and `bio`:

`https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/search?q=kellyslater`

```
{
  "username": "kellyslater",
  "bio": "#Whappen?",
  "website": "http://aspworldtour.com",
  "profile_picture": "http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_8139971_75sq_1333949277.jpg",
  "full_name": "kellyslater",
  "id": "8139971"
}
```

However, when you hit the `users/{user-id}/media/recent` endpoint, you can see that these user fields are still returned, but are not populated (this seems to be consistent, and it makes no difference if I follow that user / that user follows me, or not):

`https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/8139971/media/recent`

```
{
  "user": {
    "username": "kellyslater",
    "website": "",
    "profile_picture": "http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_8139971_75sq_1333949277.jpg",
    "full_name": "kellyslater",
    "bio": "",
    "id": "8139971"
  }
}
```

So the question is; what is the intended behaviour?

- Should the Instagram API return, and populate these fields?
- Should the Instagram API NOT return these fields at all?
- Or is it working as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instagram resolved this with a release in March 2015; http://developers.instagram.com/post/112826291271/api-bug-fixes

In summary it was a bug;

> There has been a long standing bug where some endpoints containing the ‘user’ node would have empty ‘bio’ and ‘website’ fields. We have now removed those fields from all endpoints except /users/ and /users/self.